# Does the graph exist with vertex degrees $(11,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1)$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Does the graph exist with vertex degrees $(11,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1)$? Is it possible that a degree of a vertex can be $11$? However, there are only $9$ vertices. Does the graph exist?

Comment: A path with 9 vertices, and five loops on one end vertex?

Comment: As pointed out by @Gordon, it exists if you include multigraphs (allow parallel edges and loops).  Otherwise, it is not possible for simple graphs.

Comment: Thanks so much ! I have solved the question by using multigraphs. @TravisJ

Answer (score 1):

If you are considering simple graphs, no, such a graph does not exist by exactly your reasoning. But if you consider multigraphs or graphs with loops, sure such a graph exists. In fact many such graphs exist. Here's a silly example: let the degree-$11$ vertex and the degree-$1$ vertex be connected, and let every other edge in the graph be a loop.